# Straight line on a mobius strip

Tags: geodesic, mobius-band

I have a mobius strip that is twisted by 540° degrees (not only 180° as the usual mobius strip).
Also it is one that can't be constructed with a paper-strip.

I created it with this OpenSCAD code:

```
for(angle = [0:0.3:360])
    rotate([0, 0, angle])
        translate([80, 0, 0]
            rotate([0, -angle/2*3, 0])
                cube([60, 0.5, 1], center=true);
```

The result looks like this: [Mobius Strip with 540° twist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmwgF.png)
So far so good.

Now I would like to wrap an LED-Strip around it.
But I'm just not able to figure out the mathematics.
I think maybe Geodesic could be the way to solve this.
But I also read that these are usually second order differential equations to solve which is way above my skills.

I'm looking for something like a formula or an algorithm of the path of the LED-Strip.

I tried to apply the LED-Strip by hand.
It worked out quite well but is just not perfect:
[First Try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLmGm.jpg)

Any help or hints are welcome. Many Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> It's not difficult to [write down a parametrization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4358367/removing-zero-sections-of-n-twisted-strips) of such a strip. On the other hand, the question appears to be about building a physical model, and it's not clear to me what help a mathematical description provides...? <> Separately, I don't understand the part about "can't be constructed from a paper strip." Does that mean paper doesn't physically twist the desired way?

Comment: As far as my understanding goes, there are two types of mobius strips: Does that can be created with a straight paper strip (for example: [link](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:M%C3%B6bius_strip.jpg)) and does that can't because they have plane curves in it (for example: [link](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:M%C3%B6biusband.png)). I'm using the second type.

Comment: To create a physical model I first need the mathematical representation: My problem is that I have a mobius strip with plane curves in it. So it can't be created with a straight paper strip. Now I wan't to add an LED-Strip which basically is a paper strip. I think it should be possible as I almost achieved it as you can see in: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLmGm.jpg). So now I try to figure out how to exactly define the path of the LED-Strip. And that is why I need the help of the mathematics.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "plane curves." Every surface has "plane curves" in it. As @AndrewD.Hwang is describing, your issue is one of the Gaussian curvature of the Möbius strip.

Answer (score 1):

The Möbius strip in the CAD model and photograph are formed by revolving a line segment at constant speed in a longitudinal plane. When the segment revolves through three half-turns, this strip may be described parametrically as
$$
x(\rho, \phi) = ((R + \rho\cos\tfrac{3}{2}\phi)\cos\phi, (R + \rho\cos\tfrac{3}{2}\phi)\sin\phi, \rho\sin\tfrac{3}{2}\phi),\qquad
-r \leq \rho \leq r,\ 0 \leq \phi \leq 2\pi.
$$
It's true that this strip cannot be made *exactly* out of paper. The issue is not that the surface contains a plane curve (all Möbius strips contain plane curves, where the strip is cut by a plane), but that is has non-zero [Gaussian curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature). Non-zero Gaussian curvature is an issue with _every  familiar model, however, including the [photograph of the strip made from actual paper](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:M%C3%B6bius_strip.jpg), see note below.

If the LED strip is not sitting nicely on the surface despite the surface being smooth in the physical sense, that's likely due to the surface's non-zero Gaussian curvature. Qualitatively, an untwisted LED strip has the same length at each location across its width, but even a narrow band of surface has varying length at different locations across its width. The effect can be reduced by increasing the radius of the strip's central circle, or by using a different parametrization, but I'm not sure that suits the model-building purposes, and I don't know of a good parametrization to suggest offhand.

---

Technical note: In Euclidean three-space, there exists no Möbius strip that is *real-analytic* and developable, i.e., with Gaussian curvature zero. (I first learned this as a student from Morris Hirsch.) This fact is possibly under-appreciated; it certainly is not quoted widely. In fact, a quick search yields a number of web sites that appear to claim otherwise.

Loosely, this means any surface we can write down with formulas (such as the parametrization above, which is real-analytic) does not give a mathematically-flat surface.

There do exist flat (and real-analytic) abstract Möbius strips. The claim about is about images of real-analytic parametrizations in Euclidean three-space.

There do exist *smooth* flat Möbius strips in Euclidean three-space, but the only examples I know of are not band-like. (They all contain planar regions where "the direction of bending changes".)

Comment: If I understand correctly there is no formula that solves my problem. But I would also be happy with a numerical solution e.g. a good enough approximation. Could there be an algorithm or an approximation to solve my problem? What would it look like?

Comment: Just came across the relevant paper whose details I couldn't recall: _The equilibrium shape of an elastic developable Mobius strip_ by E.L. Starostin and G.H.M. van der Heijden, Proc. Appl. math. Mech., **7**, 2020115-2020116, DOI 10.1002/pamm.200700858, see also this [response](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.2021.0856). This strip cannot be flat for the reasons mentioned, but the paper and subsequent discussion seem likely to be of interest.